# Getting activation key from cmd does not work - Win10

Tags: cmd

I want to get my windows 10 activation key with cmd and when I run this cmd:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

it shows me OA3xOriginalProductKey and below this 2 blank rows. Why can't I get my windows activation key with this cmd ?

Comment: It is encrypted. Try running this command after running the cmd as admin or use the following PowerShell command: `powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey"`.

Comment: That powershell still returns nothing for me. We (university) have our own licensing server and pay a ~$100 yearly fee per seat for Windows + Office updates.

Answer (score 0):

> If the device has a firmware-embedded activation key, it will be
>   displayed in the output. If the output is blank, the device does not
>   have a firmware embedded activation key. Most OEM-provided devices
>   designed to run Windows 8 or later will have a firmware-embedded key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-enterprise-licenses